# Couldn't get files under specific revision on SVN

Tags: svn, svnkit

My project uses `SVNKit` to checkout files programmatically from one `(repo A)` and check into another `(repo B)`.

All files in `repo A` were checked in by Eclipse in advance.

Users designate specific file under specific revision on `repo A`, and the program will copy it from `repo A` to `repo B`.

It works fine most of time, but fails under following condition:

**ex:**

1. At beginning, i checked in files, ex: `InfoStruc.java`, to `repo A`, and it returns me the revision number (ex:61)
2. User selects `InfoStruc.java` on revision 2 to transfer. (In fact, any revision from `1~60` all fail )

The following error message returned

> > org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: '/svntest/arthur/!svn/bc/2/DPS/src/main/java/idv/arthur/work/InfoStruc.java' path not found: 404 Not Found (http://10.134.231.56)

After many commitment on repo A, the revision of `InfoStruc.java` increased to 946.
And it still gets error on revision from `1~60`, but works fine on `61~946`.

My subversion server's version is `1.6.11`.
And SVNKit is `1.7.8`.

Comment: I don't understand.  A file was first created at revision 61 and you are surprised that retrieving this file from revision 2 fails?

Comment: Yeah, I totally commit this file two times, the first revision is 61, and the second is 946, but I could select all revision between (61~946). So I think I ought to be able to select (1~60) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "works as designed".  If `file` in `repo` was created at revision 61, you can refer to `repo@60` and you can refer to `repo/file@61` but you cannot refer to `repo/file@60` because, as the error message indicates, that refers to something which did not exist at that revision.  It's not altogether conceptually different from attempting to refer to a file which doesn't exist.

Comment: Why `SVN` doesn't complete the 1~60 absence just as what it did on 62~945? Is there any way(by API) to distinguish which revision is the beginning revision? When I call the method `getRevision` in `SVNDirEntry`, it always returns the maximum revision, and it might lead user to select the revision not existed.

Comment: If the file was created at revision 61, it certainly still exists in revision 62, so you can refer to it.  Perhaps your model of what a "revision" represents is different from SVN's?  A revision means "this is what the project looked like at a particular point in time".  You can refer to any artefact in the project; if it hasn't changed since revision 61, then what you get is what it looked like in revision 61, simply because it's still true in the revision you are referring to. The truth prior to revision 61 is "file does not exist".